# hokuyo_node error code 15->15

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

our hokuyo laser has suddenly stopped working.
On rosrun-ing hokuyo_node the following error message is displayed:

`[ERROR] [1315484154.288808300]: Laser returned abnormal status message, aborting: Trouble!! Error Code=[15->15] You may be able to find further information at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting/`

The mentioned wiki page doesn't cover our error code and mentions that these codes are undocumented. None of the offered solutions fix the error, which has been preventing us from using the hokuyo for a week now.

Does anyone know what this error code means or how to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11150/hokuyo_node-error-code-15-%3E15/) by [p schwab](https://answers.ros.org/users/1056/p-schwab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The protocol definition also lists error code 15 as "Others".

So, the hokuyo worked fine and now suddenly doesn't anymore after you power cycled the Hokuyo and rebooted the system it's running on? You can also try another computer to be safe.

Unfortunately, in that case I think there is a problem with the hokuyo itself. You can try checking that the power is OK and data connection is worked. Also see if the output of `dmesg` shows any errors when you plug it in.

As a minimal test on the software site you can try connection with a terminal program to the device (e.g. gtkterm) and send the V command (basically V). The hokuyo should reply with version information.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [p schwab](https://answers.ros.org/users/1056/p-schwab/) on 2011-09-13**:
sorry for the late answer, no it didnt spin up anymore. We have kindly been lended another hokuyo from our friends in styria, and it works just fine. So to resolve this problem for other users: error code 15->15 indicates hardware failure

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-09-08**:
That doesn't sound so good. Does it spin up at all? You can hear that.

**Comment by [p schwab](https://answers.ros.org/users/1056/p-schwab/) on 2011-09-08**:
Dmesg is not reporting any errors. Power is on and data connection succeeds on our windows machine - but it also can't read any data from the laser..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi p schwab,

You should contact to your provider or directly to Hokuyo since this seems to be a hardware problem.

If this happens when you are scanning, the Communication Protocol Specification for SCIP2.0's Table 3 of the page 15/32 says that errors from 10 to 17 are "Others" (temporary document from 4/12/2009)

Anyway, have you tried Hokuyo drivers? You can find them here: [www.hokuyo-aut.co.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/urg_programs](http://www.hokuyo-aut.co.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/urg_programs/index.html) There is a sample program that can give you some more information.

We had problems with one UTM30LX (the red light blinked instead of keep on) they had to update the firmware, but now there's a tool which you can do it by yourself.

I hope this helps you a bit.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [p schwab](https://answers.ros.org/users/1056/p-schwab/) on 2011-09-08**:
Yes, we just tried using some of the demo applications hokuyo provides for windows - the configuration tools work fine.. however the UrgViewer which should record data from the laser is simply not doing anything, I suspect that is due to the lack of error handling in those applications.